# Return first matching record for a query per user, activerecord rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

I have a `Log` model with an associated `User` model in a Rails 3 app using Activerecord and MySQL. A `Log` has two attributes: a string called `label` and a `timestamp`. I would like to find every `Log` which had a `label` containing the string "create" but I only want the query to return one record per user and furthermore I want the first record matching these conditions with regards to the `timestamp` attribute. Let me know if that is too confusing and I'll try to be more clear.

A slow way to do this might be...

```
logs=[]
User.all.each do |u|
  logs << Log.where("label like ? and user_id = ?","%create%", u.id).order('timestamp').limit(1)[0]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this is the general idea:

`Log.select("DISTINCT user_id, *").where("label like ?","%create%", u.id).order('timestamp').group("user_id").includes(:user)`